# A-frame :Force fusing controls on desktop

Tags: cursor, aframe

I am really sorry if the response is somewhere, but I am looking for the solution since yesterday and only find old posts I don't really understand/propose things which don't work anymore. :(

I want to do something like that : https://sandbox.donmccurdy.com/checkpoints/

Which mean force the "fuse control" (?) to be active on desktop, and the camera follow the mouse which is symbolize by the circle on the middle of the screen.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lock the camera to the mouse, just use the `pointerLockEnabled` property of the `look-controls`:

```
<a-entity camera look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: true"></a-camera>
```

Live codepen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vreRdY).